# Prove that the set:$S=\lbrace{x\rbrace}\cup\lbrace{\lbrace{x,y\rbrace}:x\neq y,x,y\in X\rbrace}$ is a topological basis of X.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\neq\lbrace{\emptyset\rbrace}$.
I did not succeed in showing that the set above is a topological basis of $X$?
Could anyone provide me tips
Thanks

Comment: If you are not told what $X$ is you cannot write $x+1, x-1$ etc.

Comment: Yes, then how can I show that the orders really work?

Comment: In general if we don't know what topological space $X$ is, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Yes! Can anyone edit the question for me, i didn't manage to edit it, i meant S={x}\cup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check that fo a set $X$ and some fixed $x \in X$ the collection of subsets of $X$, $\mathcal{S}_x := \{\{x\}\} \cup \{\{x,y\}: y \neq x\}$ defines a base for a topology on $X$.

Check the two standard conditions:

1. $\bigcup \mathcal{S}_x=X$, because $x \in \{x\} \in \mathcal{S}_x$ and if $y \neq x$, $y\in \{y,x\} \in \mathcal{S}_x$ so every point of $X$ is in some base element.
2. Suppose $z \in B_1 \cap B_2$, where $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{S}_x$. The only way that can happen for two distinct base elements (the only relevant case) is when $z=x$ and $B_1 = \{x,z_1\}$ or $B_1 = \{x\}$ and $B_2 = \{x,z_2\}$ (or the other way around), as the sets of $\mathcal{S}_x$ only intersect in $x$. But then we can just take $B_3 = \{x\}$ to satisfy $z \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$ as required.

This base generates the so-called *included point topology* $\mathcal{T}_x=\{A \subseteq X: A = \emptyset \lor x \in A\}$, if you think about it..

Comment: Thank you so much for your deep answer!